# How to determine how many messages are written on FIFO?

Tags: c, posix, named-pipes, fifo

I want to monitor my named pipe and read it's contents once it received 5 messages from another process. Is there a way to count how many times messages are written on pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Most FIFO implementations have a length() subfunction. You also could check the index or address of the next element off the FIFO against the address of the index or address of where the next element added to the FIFO will go.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are not message-oriented they are just streams, once you write into it it is impossible to know how these data were written.